# platform.pause.subscribe at Ionic-React

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework

I am using `Ionic` Framework with `React`. I want to run a code when platform.pause as mentioned in [ionic-react-platform](https://ionicframework.com/docs/angular/platform).
But the codes in react documents are unbelievably for angular instead of react!

I want exactly code below, but for react not for angular. Can any one help me with it please?

```
import { Platform } from '@ionic/angular';

@Component({...})
export class MyPage {
  constructor(public platform: Platform) {

  }

  init(){
    this.platform.pause.subscribe(async () => {
      alert('Pause event detected');
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try by setting a listener inside your App component (or wherever you need it)

```
import { App } from '@capacitor/app';

App.addListener('appStateChange', ({ isActive }) => {
  // state.isActive contains the active state
  console.log('App state changed. Is App in foreground?', isActive);
});
```